# Remove a specific string from a char variable in sas

Tags: sas

I'm trying to remove a string from a var in sas.

```
Data test;
a='27,7,37';
b=7;
c=trnwrd(a,strip(put(b,2.)),'');
run;
```

I want to remove only the second 7 from the string a, not the 7 from 27,37.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tranwrd`, use `transtrn` with a 3rd argument (the replacement) being a zero-length string returned by `trimN('')`

```
c = transtrn ( a, cats(',',b), trimN(''));
```

transtrn could be 'too strong'.  For example, if `a="1,7,7,7,727";` the `transtrn` would eliminate **all** the `,7` occurrences.

A more robust match and replace can be done with `PRXCHANGE`

```
Data test;
array s [10] $100 _temporary_ (
  '27,7,37'
, '27,7,7,7,7,7,737' 
, '27,7'                %* <------ prxchange does not remove ,7 -- PCRE should! bug in SAS ? ;
, '27,77'
, ',7,4,5,6'
, ',7,7,7,7'
);

b = 7;

length patternTemplate $50;
patternTemplate = 's/^([^,]*),(#b#)($|,)/$1$3/';
pattern = tranwrd (patternTemplate, '#b#', cats(b));

put /pattern=/;

do i = 1 to dim(s) while (not missing(s[i]));

  a = s[i];

  c = prxchange(pattern,1,a);
  put a=/c=/;

  output

end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prxchange as follows

```
data test;
length a $50.;
a='27,7,37';output;
a='7,7,7';output;
 a='7,97,7';output;
 a='44,7,57,78,79,66';output;
 run;
```

in the below code

```
    ^(\d+) indicates first starting number a
    (\,7)  -- indicates  second number 
     (.+) -- everything after second number
```

first and last parts are captured as $1 and $3 are replaced which means we are eliminating second 7. if it does not find this pattern it does nothing

```
 data want;
 set test;
 a1=prxchange('s/^(\d+)(\,7)(.+)/$1$3/',1, a);
 run;
```